# Entity Framework : a second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a .NET project that uses Entity Framework and I am encountering threading issues with my `DbContext`. When multiple threads try to access the `DbContext` simultaneously, I am getting various exceptions such as

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext.

I have tried several solutions, including creating a new instance of the `DbContext` for each thread, but I have not been able to resolve the issue.

Here is a simplified version of the code that is causing the problem:

```
/// task processer
public async Task ProcessAsync()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var task in IntradayTasks!.Concat(WeekdayTasks!)!)
    {
        tasks.Add(ProcessTaskAsync(task));
    }
      
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

async Task ProcessTaskAsync(Core.Entities.Tasks tasks)
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

    var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ITaskUnitOfWorkRepository>>();

    ITaskUnitOfWorkRepository taskUnitOfWorkRepository = new TaskUnitOfWorkRepository(_dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(), logger);
    var taskManager = new TaskManagerDecorator(new TaskManager(taskUnitOfWorkRepository), taskUnitOfWorkRepository);
    var logId = await taskManager.LogTaskEventAsync(tasks, CancellationToken.None);

    ITaskStateContext taskStateContext = new TaskStateContext(new ProcessState(), taskUnitOfWorkRepository);

    try
    {
        await taskStateContext.Process(tasks);
        await TaskUtilities.InvokeTask(tasks.ClassName!, tasks.MetaData!, _serviceScopeFactory);
        await taskStateContext.Complete(tasks);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await taskStateContext.Failed(tasks);
        _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        await taskManager.LogTaskEventAsync(logId, tasks, CancellationToken.None);
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

I would expect the `dbContext` not to throw any exceptions since each method call to process task creates it's own instance of `dbContext`

Comment: Are you sure all those methods `await` for all context I/O?

Comment: Eliminating the obvious, but `_dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext()` actually new's up a DbContext, and isn't doing something like returning a cached reference or IoC provided  instance?

Comment: One bug I see: `var scope = `, should be `using var scope = `. Show also `TaskUtilities.InvokeTask` and actually you have to pass into this function `scope`.

Comment: Is your service Singleton ?

Comment: Like Steve said, you are not disposing it after each thread is completed, which can lead to the issue of multiple threads accessing the same instance of DbContext. Try warping the DbContext creation within a using statement.

Comment: @XiaotianYang, I have already mentioned that, `scope` should be disposed. `DbContext` created in scope will be disposed automatically.

Comment: disposing  TaskUtilities.InvokeTask fixed the issue

Thanks!!